# return a string from array

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just want to return a string from an array in vue.
I made method like this:

```
displayFixturesName() {
                const result = this.selectedFixture.toString();
                document.getElementById('resultFixture').innerHTML = result.join()

            }
```

`this.selectedFixture` is an array of my selection

and I display it like this

```
<p class="subtitle" id="resultFixture">{{displayFixturesName()}}</p>
```

Finally, I have a message in my console and it doesn't work-

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: result.join is not a function"

Comment: `join()` is a function which works only with `array` but you used it on `string` (because you have used `toString()` function before).

Comment: Since `result` is already a string, why don't you simply print it? `join` is an Array method. Otherwise, if `this.selectedFixture` is an array, just do `this.selectedFixture.join()`. In any case, using a method is not the cleverest approach in any MVC framework.

Comment: You shouldn't be manipulating the DOM inside the method. Use a computed property instead and just return the string.

Comment: thanks , I forget to delete this method.

Comment: Can you tell me if it's possible to make space after each coma in join() ?

Comment: @Sébastian `.join(', ');`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @skirtle can you tell me more about that ?

Comment: Now I have another problem in my console

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this in Vue is to use a computed property to return the string:

```js
computed: {
  displayFixturesName() {
    return this.selectedFixture.join(', ');
  }
}
```

Then in the template you'd have:

```html
<p class="subtitle">{{ displayFixturesName }}</p>
```

I've removed the `id` (you shouldn't need it, Vue has `ref` if you need to grab an element) and also the `()` from after `displayFixturesName`.

Generally you should avoid manipulating the DOM yourself, just leave Vue to do it. There are a few exceptions, such as working with third-party libraries or measuring sizes, but they are rare.

The documentation on computed properties is here:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not related to VUE, but to the usage of [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
As *Jax-p* [pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340930/return-a-string-from-array#comment103037037_58340930) already, this method does not exist on strings, only on arrays. Your `.join()` call will implicitly out

I've reduced your example to plain JavaScript to demonstrate how you could use the method.

```js
const fixture = ["selected", "Fixture"];
console.log(fixture.join());
```